# Creating svg elements inside a Ember collection view

Tags: svg, ember.js, d3.js

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/232/), I am trying to push a SVG `circle` element when adding a new item into an array through `Ember.CollectionView`. But seems that the `g` element is not getting created in the SVG namespace and hence:

- the `g` element is getting added into the dom
- but the `g` element does not have the properties of an SVG node when looking up in the DOM inspector.
- the `g` element is not being rendered within the `SVG` element.

Not sure if the issue is related to Ember or D3. I am doubtful that the `g` tag that Ember creates should be created with the proper `xmlns` namespace for SVG, but not sure how to get it worked around.

Comment: That is strange the context binding is working correctly when the content array is initialized, but not when you add any other objects.

Comment: Not quite sure yet. But it seems like ember issue. I notice that new <g> tag doesn't have: "-webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
-webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;
-webkit-transform-origin-z: initial;"

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?  I am having the exact same problem in my application and don't know how to fix it.  Please update if you have a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I've managed to fix it. You can't use Ember for creating SVG elements, as ember uses the default 'HTML' namespace for creating new elements. SVG, on the other hand, requires elements to be created using `document.createElementNS`. I ended up using d3 inside a ember View's `didInsertElement`. Thanks for asking!

Comment: I see. I have a `Graphs` view which is an SVG element, inside of which I have many `Graph` views, each of which is a `g` element. I am using d3 within the `Graph` view and that seems to work until the number of graphs change, and then it breaks.  I could theoretically use d3 to manipulate all of my graphs directly, but my `Graph` view is fairly complicated so it would require lots of code rewriting and anti-refactoring.  Was hoping for an Ember-side solution.  So there is no method we can overwrite to change Ember's document creation mechanism?

Comment: Not that I found about. You could use d3's join mechanism (`enter`, `update` and `exit` ) for maintaining the views in d3, which is what I ended up doing. You could place your question as a separate fiddle which I could attempt at.

Comment: My fiddle would look essentially exactly like your fiddle if I dumbed it down.  So in your solution, you have one `Ember.CirclesView` (or equivalent) in which you manipulated all your `g` elements via d3, right?  I could do that too but my `g` elements are quite complex.  Doable though, if that's the only solution you have found :)

Comment: I use both `paper.js` and `d3` in conjunction with Ember. Usually on `didInsertElement`, I set up whatever svg plot I need and then redraw it when any of the ember bindings change, using observers and such. I haven't had any major problems combining Ember with these libraries.